# SwiftUI summing Text views dynamically

Tags: swiftui

I want to add Text views together to apply different formatting to different parts of the text. Eg, I can do this:

```
HStack {
  Text("first ").font(.title)
  + Text("second ").font(.largeTitle)
  + Text("third").font(.headline)
}
```

But my case is dynamic, I want to iterate over an array of strings and for each string, create a Text() with particular formatting. Something like:

```
HStack {
  ForEach(words) { w in
    Text(w).font(getFont(w))
  }
```

But the above doesn't sum, and thus is subject to spacing/line-break issues. I really do want to be able to add the Text() objects together.

Any ideas?

Comment: Search for Attributed String for SwiftUI. Apple just started supporting it last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, based on the comment from @lorem, I found:

https://swiftui-lab.com/attributed-strings-with-swiftui/

And that did it, but it ain't pretty.